# Volley - Sending a POST request using JSONArrayRequest

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm using Volley to interact with an API. I need to send a post request (with parameters) to a service that returns a JSON Array.

JsonObjectRequest has a constructor that takes a method and a set of parameters

```
JsonObjectRequest(int method, java.lang.String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
```

However JSONArrayRequest (the one I need) only has one constructor of the form

```
JsonArrayRequest(java.lang.String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
```

How can I make this send a POST request with data?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

They're probably going to add it later, but in the meanwhile you can add the wanted constructor yourself:

```
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
        Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), 
        listener, errorListener);
}
```

This isn't tested, though I see no reason this shouldn't work since the implementation details are in the super class: `JsonRequest`.

Try it and see if it works.

### EDIT:

I called it! It took them almost two years after I answered this but the Volley team added this constructor on March 19, 2015 to the repo. Guess what? This is the EXACT syntax.

Comment: Actually discovered this myself poking around the code last night. Thanks anyway though. Works like a charm.

Comment: Hello, where you write this code in fact? And how super(...) can work because the default constructor is like this : JsonArrayRequest(java.lang.String url,Response.Listener<org.json.JSONArray> listener,ErrorListener errorListener)

Comment: The super constructor belongs to the "parent" class, `JsonRequest<JSONArray>`, which `JsonArrayRequest` inherits from, that's why it works. I think you were confusing it with a call to a constructor using `this`. You need to add that code in JsonArrayRequest.java (inside the toolbox package).

Comment: This is an accepted answer with 8 up votes. That probably means that your problem is not with this constructor but with your server response. Debug your code and see.

Comment: TAKE NOTE: The official volley does not have this constructor. This one can be found in the deprecated and unofficial volley: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

Answer (score 7):

I was lazy and did not build the Volley library myself (just used the .jar), hence have no source code...so in the anonymous new `JSONArrayRequest` I added these functions:

```
            // NO CONSTRUCTOR AVAILABLE FOR POST AND PARAMS FOR JSONARRAY!
            // overridden the necessary functions for this
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                try {
                    return paramsArray.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public int getMethod() {
                return Method.POST;
            }
```

Comment: Your answer is easier for beginner who just used .jar. @Itai answer makes beginner like me confused.

Comment: Aye, and you can subclass JSONArrayRequest directly, rather than write it anew.

Comment: what is param array ?

Comment: @k2ibegin not sure anymore XD but i guess it was just list of data needed by the server. But I guess it can be anything you want

Answer (score 2):

This code will make what you want

```
    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(
            new JsonRequest<JSONArray>(Request.Method.POST, "url/", null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("param1", "one");
                    params.put("param2", "two");
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(
                        NetworkResponse response) {
                    try {
                        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                                HttpHeaderParser
                                        .parseCharset(response.headers));
                        return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                                HttpHeaderParser
                                        .parseCacheHeaders(response));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                    } catch (JSONException je) {
                        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Strange data sent using `getParam()` isn't received on server, else it works fine. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The best and easy way to send parameter request and return custom response according to parameter using JSONarray Request is to add get paramater value in the URL itself.

```
String URL ="http://mentormentee.gear.host/android_api/Message.aspx?key="+keyvalue;
```

where `keyvalue` parameter value and add this URL in the JsonArrayRequest URL simple.

```
    JsonArrayRequest searchMsg= new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


            // Parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {

                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.setMessageThread(obj.getString("msgThread"));
                    msg.setUserName(obj.getString("Username"));
                    msg.setDate(obj.getString("msgDate"));

                    // adding movie to movies array
                    MessageList.add(msg);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            // notifying list adapter about data changes
            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
           // hidePDialog();

        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(searchMsg);
}
```

Comment: is there any need to add extra thing on server side php

Answer (score 1):

May be your problem is solved but I hope this will be helpful for other users. What I did was, I created a new custom class by extending it.. here is the code.

```
public class CustomJsonRequest extends Request {

Map<String, String> params;       
private Response.Listener listener; 

public CustomJsonRequest(int requestMethod, String url, Map<String, String> params,
                      Response.Listener responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(requestMethod, url, errorListener);
    this.params = params;
    this.listener = responseListener;
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(Object response) {
    listener.onResponse(response); 

}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
         return params;
}

@Override
protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

}
```

you can use this class instead of JsonArrayRequest or JSonObjectRequest. And this also solve the problem of php not being able to catch post parameter in $_POST

Comment: Actually it works but I need something else. In my case my params is a Json Object or sometimes a Json Array. How can I use your code for my need??

Comment: @FlavienBert You can do type inspection on the json object to figure out if you need to return an array or an object. `Object json = new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue(); if (json instanceof JSONObject) { } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) { }`

Comment: Oh thank God!  I've been banging my head on this and this worked, just had to alter `return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),` to JSONArray for my needs.  I am however curious why I was having a hard time with mine, if you have a sec and wouldn't mind taking a look I have a post here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837859/using-custom-volley-post-doesnt-return-anything)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this 

package HelperClass;
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2011 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */



import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener;
import com.android.volley.Response.Listener;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * A request for retrieving a {@link JSONArray} response body at a given URL.enter code here
 */
public class MyjsonPostRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {

    protected static final String PROTOCOL_CHARSET = "utf-8";



    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param method the HTTP method to use
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param requestBody A {@link String} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
     *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public MyjsonPostRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody,
                            Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, requestBody, listener,
                errorListener);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public MyjsonPostRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param method the HTTP method to use
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public MyjsonPostRequest(int method, String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param method the HTTP method to use
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONArray} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
     *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public MyjsonPostRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray jsonRequest,
                            Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                errorListener);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param method the HTTP method to use
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONObject} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
     *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public MyjsonPostRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
                            Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                errorListener);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor which defaults to <code>GET</code> if <code>jsonRequest</code> is
     * <code>null</code>, <code>POST</code> otherwise.
     *
     * @see #MyjsonPostRequest(int, String, JSONArray, Listener, ErrorListener)
     */
    public MyjsonPostRequest(String url, JSONArray jsonRequest, Listener<JSONArray> listener,
                            ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this(jsonRequest == null ? Method.GET : Method.POST, url, jsonRequest,
                listener, errorListener);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor which defaults to <code>GET</code> if <code>jsonRequest</code> is
     * <code>null</code>, <code>POST</code> otherwise.
     *
     * @see #MyjsonPostRequest(int, String, JSONObject, Listener, ErrorListener)
     */
    public MyjsonPostRequest(String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONArray> listener,
                            ErrorListener errorListener) {
        this(jsonRequest == null ? Method.GET : Method.POST, url, jsonRequest,
                listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add some details about JsonArrayRequest.
in \src\com\android\volley\toolbox,you can find out that default construct of JsonArrayRequest not support Method parameter, and volley add method(GET) in the construct,
so if u want to use other method, try write it yourself

```
public class JsonArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {

    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public JsonArrayRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Map<String,String>> listMap =  new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String,String> map  = new HashMap<String,String>();
        try {

            map.put("email", customer.getEmail());
            map.put("password",customer.getPassword());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listMap.add(map);

        String url = PersonalConstants.BASE_URL+"/url";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url, String.valueOf(new JSONArray(listMap)),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        Log.d(App.TAG, jsonObject.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener (){

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.d(App.TAG,volleyError.toString());
            }
        }
        );
        App.getInstance().getmRequestQueue().add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {
                            // Parsing json array response
                            // loop through each json object
                            jsonResponse = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                        .get(i);

                                String name = person.getString("name");
                                String email = person.getString("email");
                                JSONObject phone = person
                                        .getJSONObject("phone");
                                String home = phone.getString("home");
                                String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");

                                jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n\n";

                            }

                            txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```

}