# Android Volley Post Request - Workaround for JsonArrayRequest

Tags: android, android-volley

I understand that POST requests using JsonArrayRequest are not available out of the box with Volley, but I saw this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048806/volley-sending-a-post-request-using-jsonarrayrequest) that talked about adding a constructor to handle this. Their implementation was this:

```
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
        Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), 
        listener, errorListener);
}
```

How would I go about adding this as a constructor? The above question mentions placing it in the Volley Tool Library. I imported Volley as a .jar, so I'm not sure how to add a constructor like this, or if this is the best approach. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've created the following class with override and constructor as suggested. Here is the class:

```
public class PostJsonArrayRequest extends JsonArrayRequest {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", "value");
        return params;
    }

    public PostJsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
            Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    }
}
```

On the line calling super I'm getting `The constructor JsonArrayRequest(int, String, null, Response.Listener<JSONArray>, Response.ErrorListener) is undefined`

How do I correct this?

Comment: Subclass JsonArrayRequest, put constructor there instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class and extend `JsonArrayRequest` then override

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("name", "value");
    return params;
}
```

and add a new constructor and in it call

```
super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
```

or use this class

```
public class PostJsonArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {

    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public PostJsonArrayRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", "value");
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString =
                    new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I created a class to extend `JsonArrayRequest`, added the override for Map, and added a constructor like your example. I've updated my question with the code. I'm getting an error (posted above).