# Volley - Make a jsonarray post request

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am having this class where am fetching json array with POST method after referring several google searches and stackoverflow question but my code gives an weird error `Cannot Resolve Symbol` `POST`

here is my activity

```
public class fbuk extends Activity {

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://example.com/xyz.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new PostJsonArrayRequest(Method.POST, url, null, 
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("ttl"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("img"));
                            movie.setRating(obj.getString("stts"));
                            movie.setYear(obj.getString("rel"));

                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, 
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();
                }
            });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }
}


public class PostJsonArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {

    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public PostJsonArrayRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("q", "ram");
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString =
                    new String(response.data,   HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
}
```

I am following a tutorial from androidhive

Please suggest where am making the mistake

Comment: try this, use (Request.Method.POST,url,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){.....}

Comment: Check your import for `Method`. It should be `import com.android.volley.Request.Method`

Comment: got incompatible type error

Comment: What is `PostJsonArrayRequest`??  Have you checked ur code as per my answer?

Comment: Have referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358402/android-volley-post-request-workaround-for-jsonarrayrequest to send arguments as post method and did as suggested . Its an constructor class

Comment: yes it gives incompatible type error

Comment: Show error log please. The mistake is in it. I need to check may be you'r doing mistake somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74390/discussion-between-user3225075-and-piyush-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

I have done like this (see sample code), make sure that `import com.android.volley.Request;` must be imported in your activity class otherwise `Request.Method.POST` will not work and **Unable to Resolve** will appear

```
String url = "http://example.com/xyz.php";

    ErrorListener errorListener = new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError errorResponce) 
        {

        }
    };

    Listener<JSONArray > jsonArrayListener = new Listener<JSONArray>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };


    PostJsonArrayRequest req = new PostJsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url , null, jsonArrayListener, errorListener);
```

And use this class for

```
 public class PostJsonArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> 
{

    public PostJsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody,
            Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) 
    {
        super(method, url, requestBody, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) 
    {
        try {
            String jsonString =
                    new String(response.data,   HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Error:(90, 37) error: constructor PostJsonArrayRequest in class fbuk.PostJsonArrayRequest cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,Listener<JSONArray>,ErrorListener
found: int,String,<anonymous Listener<JSONArray>>,<anonymous ErrorListener>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: I have edited the answer and add PostJsonArrayRequest class as well now check hopefully it will work.

Comment: your answer took me half way but am unable to send the params. how to do that?

Comment: please help me on this

Comment: you can override getParams method in PostJsonArrayRequest class, try this otherwise do tell me if issue not get resolve

Answer (score 0):

Check your import for `Method`. It should be

```
import com.android.volley.Request.Method
```

May be you have imported as a

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```

Comment: Error:(90, 37) error: constructor PostJsonArrayRequest in class fbuk.PostJsonArrayRequest cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,Listener<JSONArray>,ErrorListener
found: int,String,<anonymous Listener<JSONArray>>,<anonymous ErrorListener>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: You should extends your `PostJSONArrayRequest` class with `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonRequest<JSONArray>`

Comment: now i got error near super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener); cannot resolve error

Comment: You can simply use  `JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest`

Comment: how to send params then?

Comment: The format is same you just need to change `PostJSONArrayRequest` to `JSONArrayRequest`.

Comment: @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", "value");
            return params;
        } where shall i put these line of codes?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new PostJsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
```

and make sure to import,

```
import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
```

hope it will work.