# Diffrence between JsonObjectRequest & JsonArrayRequest in volley in android?

Tags: android, json, http, android-volley

Hello all i am using volley to send request to the server. I am sending some params to server & getting a json array & json object in response. As of now i am using JsonObjectRequest custom request for getting the response.If the response is JsonArray i get the json array if response is jsonObject then i get the json object.So which approach should i follow for getting the response?

```
Following is the code for sending request 
public void sendData()
{
    RequestQueue que=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("fname",fname );
    params.put("lname",lname );
    params.put("email",email );
    params.put("pswd",password);


     final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HealthCreateAccount.this);
     dialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
     dialog.setMessage("Creating Account..");
     dialog.setCancelable(false);
     dialog.show();

    CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Method.POST, url, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError response) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to Create Account!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("RAE",response.toString());
                }
            });
    que.add(jsObjRequest);

}
```

Comment: javascript: [] <= array, {} <= object ...

Comment: I am asking which approach should i getting json response? Either JsonObjectRequest or JsonArrayRequest

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048806/volley-sending-a-post-request-using-jsonarrayrequest

Comment: That link does answer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json Object & Json array is type request. Json object will try to fetch a json array where as json object will fetch json object.However you can use json object  & create a json array in a json object.