# Send ByteArray with Android volley

Tags: android, post, arrays, android-volley

There is any way to send a byte array with Volley?

Now I'm using this:

```
post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(rawPacket.toByteArray()));
try {
    response = client.execute(post);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There is something like this in Volley? There is a method to pass custom object to send with the POST/GET request?

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("RawPacket", rawPacket.toByteArray().toString());
            return params;
        }
```

I need something like `protected Map<String, ByteArray> getParams()`

Answer (score 4):

I find the solution overriding the function `public byte[] getBody()` to send custom data, I should read better the documentation!

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "https://www.example.com/",
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    }
  }) {
  @Override
  public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    return new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You should have accepted this answer

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
public class JsonArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {
/**
 * Creates a new request.
 * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
 * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
 */
public JsonArrayRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, null, listener, errorListener);
}
```

You have to create a subclass of JsonRequest and use that instead.

See related link:
[Volley - Sending a POST request using JSONArrayRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048806/volley-sending-a-post-request-using-jsonarrayrequest)

Also might want to Base64 encode the bytes and add it to the JsonArray.

Comment: Yes but how can I put custom object in the parameters that I send?

Comment: With JsonArray you store pretty much any value in it

Comment: How can I build a json with a ByteArray parameter?

Comment: Why don't you Base64 encode it and the call use put it in the JsonArray?