# Not getting any data in postExecute() method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android, I am getting data in JSON format in AsyncTask and I have some TextView's and RadioButton's. The data which I am getting in AsyncTask I want the TextView to show the same data. In doInBackground() method I am getting data properly but when i am accessing the data in postExecute() I am not gettting data.

Here is my code. 
Please Help me..

```
 String que,ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4, ans5, correct_ans, explainat;
```

In AsyncTask

```
   private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(SectionTestActivity.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Please Wait");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("Post exec calleld", "dfds");
        nDialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("Post Exeec Ques",""+que);

        sectionName.setText("" + section_category);
        question.setText("" + que.toString());
        rb_1.setText("" + ans1.toString());
        rb_2.setText("" + ans2);
        rb_3.setText("" + ans3);
        rb_4.setText("" + ans4);
        rb_5.setText("" + ans5);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(
                        new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                        SectionTestActivity.this).create();
                                alertDialog.setMessage("Error connecting to internet.");
                                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    }
                                });

                                alertDialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(

                    "http://url");
            httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            SharedPreferences preff = getSharedPreferences(
                    "MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            String userid = preff.getString("id", null);
            Log.e("Student id", "" + userid);


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("section_id", section_id);
            json.put("userid", userid);


            Log.e("JSON Object", json.toString());

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");

            httpRequest.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

            java.io.InputStream inputStream = httpRes.getEntity()
                    .getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            strServerResponse = sb.toString();
            Log.e("Server Response", "" + strServerResponse.toString());
            if (strServerResponse != null) {
                try {
                    Log.e("if block execute", "df");

                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                    pojo = new Pojo();
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                        que = jobj2.optString("title").trim();
                        qid = jobj2.optString("id").trim();
                        //qid=questionid;
                        ans1 = jobj2.optString("ans_a");
                        ans2 = jobj2.optString("ans_b");
                        ans3 = jobj2.optString("ans_c");
                        ans4 = jobj2.optString("ans_d");
                        ans5 = jobj2.optString("ans_e");
                        correct_ans = jobj2.optString("right_ans");
                        explainat = jobj2.optString("explanation");

                        Log .e("Que", ""+que);
                        Log .e("QueID", ""+qid);
                        Log .e("Ans2", ""+ans2);
                        Log .e("Ans3", ""+ans3);
                        Log .e("Ans4", ""+ans4);
                        Log .e("Ans5", ""+ans5);
                        Log .e("Ans1", ""+ans1);
                        Log .e("Correct anss", ""+correct_ans);
                        Log .e("Explll", ""+explainat);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler",
                        "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

This is JSON

```
   [{"id":"1","title":"Rahul bought a bike for Rs 24000 and sold it for 28000. What is his profit?","description":"","ans_a":"16.66%","ans_b":"20%","ans_c":"25%","ans_d":"30%","ans_e":"","right_ans":"A","explanation":"Sdcsdf sdf skdfj lsdfjlsdfj sdkjfn ;fgad"},{"rowid":93}]
```

I am not getting data here.

Comment: Please post the whole AsyncTask class, not just what's inside the methods.

Comment: @MikeM. I have posted whole AsyncTask

Comment: @Priyanka; Getting data in logs or not?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am getting data in logs in doInBackground() but not in postExecute()

Comment: did you try adding break points and debugging the app? cuz you might be getting an exception.

Comment: That's not all the code, please post the whole NetCheck class

Comment: @Neil I have added the whole NetCheck class and my JSON Object

Comment: @Priyanka use Volley and retrofit if you are getiing json from server

Comment: @Priyanka: In all views data is not showing or only in some Views?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK In all views data is not shown

Comment: Try to use Volley library.this will simplify your task.And this fast and reliable compared to other.check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014210/how-to-post-request-parameters-when-using-jsonarrayrequest-in-volley/33145641#33145641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you are looping to array and at second object you didnt have Que and other logged params hence they return empty string "" from optString if you have to get data from first object change 
`JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(0);` and not the for loop

Comment: Thanks :) Got my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want to get result in postexecute method then change the return type of doinBackground method to String,

Here am adding the skeleton example..

```
private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,String>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return "your result string";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: no need to do that... she is not tying to get data from `result` variable of post execute..