# Android Volley: Send JSONObject as parameter and to receive JSONArray as response

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I'm learning Volley library in android.
I'm using JsonObjectRequest for passing JsonObject as request parameters, And I'm getting response as a JsonArray in error listener [code for JsonObjectRequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0HzM.png) check line no.84 in image [Error in Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fvhn.png).

Can anyone help me regarding this, how to get JsonArray as response by passing JsonObject as request parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JsonArrayRequest` to capture `Array` in Response

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                            Request.Method.POST,
                            "http://lanes-dev.cloudapp.net/api/DiaryTweetLineApi/LoadDiaryTweetLinesByUser",
                            obj,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                                }
                            },
                            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                                    // Do something when error occurred

                                }
                            }
                    );
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried using JsonArrayRequest but it is not accepting jsonobject as parameter.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33014210/how-to-post-request-parameters-when-using-jsonarrayrequest-in-volley) solved my problem :)