# Volley JSONArrayRequest - not sending params properly?

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

I've tried with normal `JSONArrayRequests` and `StringRequests` and everything was fine untill now. I want to send an `JSONArrayRequest` with POST parameters to get some MySQL result in JSON format from the script. Unfortunately I get `[]` everytime in response. I have checked .php file and query with `_GET` method and the script worked perfectly returning desired rows in `Json` format.
I read here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18052417/4959185) Volley Team have added `JSONArrayRequest` with `_POST` parameter to their class. However it does not work in my case. Could you please look what is wrong with that function:

```
    private void getFavouriteRecipes(final String userUniqueId, final int offset) {

    JsonArrayRequest favouriteRecipesReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_GETFAVOURITERECIPES, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("odpowiedz", "Odpowiedź ulubionych: " + response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            RecipeItem recipeItem = new RecipeItem();
                            recipeItem.setRecipeUniqueID(jObj.getString("unique_id"));
                            recipeItem.setRecipeTitle(jObj.getString("title"));
                            recipeItem.setRecipeImgThumbnailLink(jObj.getString(
                                    "img_tumbnail_link"));
                            recipeItem.setRecipeAddAte(jObj.getString("add_date"));
                            recipeItem.setRecipeKitchenType(jObj.getString("kitchen_type"));
                            recipeItem.setRecipeMealType(jObj.getString("meal_type"));
                            recipeItem.setRecipeName(jObj.getString("name"));
                            recipeItem.setRecipeSurname(jObj.getString("surname"));
                            recipeItem.setRecipeLikeCount(jObj.getString("like_count"));
                            recipeFavouriteItems.add(recipeItem);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            showSnackbarInfo("Błąd Json: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    R.color.snackbar_error_msg);
                        }
                    }
                    recipeFavouriteItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("odpowiedz", "Błąd pobierania ulubionych: " +
                            Integer.toString(error.networkResponse.statusCode));

                    showSnackbarInfo(Integer.toString(error.networkResponse.statusCode),
                            R.color.snackbar_error_msg);
                }

            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting Parameters to Login URL
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_unique_id", userUniqueId);
            params.put("offset", Integer.toString(offset));

            Log.d(TAG, "wysylam parametry: " + userUniqueId + ", " + Integer.toString(offset));
            return params;
        }
    };

    // Adding Request to Request Queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(favouriteRecipesReq);
}
```

**My PHP Script:**
https://ideone.com/ZxYzHr

Comment: Have you actually tested your script with `POST` since you send the request like that ?

Comment: I have tested my php script only with _GET method and it worked well. Why it shouldn't work with _POST? Just different type of sending parameters.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your script, I was just wondering why you're not testing it with POST as well to see if the script returns correctly. If it does, then you're sure that the problem is on the client side (Android).

Comment: I have added link to it in my edit. Pls check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another way to get JSONArrayResponse with sending parameters. I think that will help somebody.

U just write standard JSONArrayRequest liek this:

```
JsonArrayRequest favouriteRecipesReq = new JsonArrayRequest(prepareGetMethodUrl(),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d("odpowiedz", "Odpowiedź ulubionych: " + response.toString());

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jObj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                RecipeItem recipeItem = new RecipeItem();
                                recipeItem.setRecipeUniqueID(jObj.getString("unique_id"));
                                recipeItem.setRecipeTitle(jObj.getString("title"));
                                recipeItem.setRecipeImgThumbnailLink(jObj.getString(
                                        "img_tumbnail_link"));
                                recipeItem.setRecipeAddAte(jObj.getString("add_date"));
                                recipeItem.setRecipeKitchenType(jObj.getString("kitchen_type"));
                                recipeItem.setRecipeMealType(jObj.getString("meal_type"));
                                recipeItem.setRecipeName(jObj.getString("name"));
                                recipeItem.setRecipeSurname(jObj.getString("surname"));
                                recipeItem.setRecipeLikeCount(jObj.getString("like_count"));
                                recipeFavouriteItems.add(recipeItem);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        recipeFavouriteItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("odpowiedz", "Błąd pobierania ulubionych: " +
                                Integer.toString(error.networkResponse.statusCode));

                        showSnackbarInfo(Integer.toString(error.networkResponse.statusCode),
                                R.color.snackbar_error_msg);
                    }

                });

        // Adding Request to Request Queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(favouriteRecipesReq);
```

Instead of standard URL to the PHP script I inserted function returning `String` called `prepareGetMethodUrl()`.

Let's look inside it:

```
private String prepareGetMethodUrl() {
    return AppConfig.URL_GETFAVOURITERECIPES + "?user_unique_id=" + userUniqueId + "&offset=" +
            Integer.toString(offset);
}
```

As you can see it's very simple. I get standard `AppConfig.URL_GETFAVOURITERECIPES` which is static field in AppConfig class conatining direct link to my PHP script on my serwer f.e `http://www.someserversite.com/my_api/gmy_php_script.php` and combine it with parametres values I need to send to the script: `user_unique_id` and it's content `userUniqueId` and `offset` which content is `offset` parsed from `int` to `String`.

Inside my script I just call:

```
<?php
// some code

// Receiving The Post Params
$user_unique_id = $_GET['user_unique_id'];
$offset = $_GET['offset'];

echo $user_unique_id . "<br />";
echo $offset;
?>
```