# Unable to make jsonarrayrequest with volley

Tags: android, android-volley

Im trying to make a post request with volley.

The request parameter is a json array .

Following is my request parameter

```
[
 "Type",
 {
  "User": "email",
  "password": "dimmer",

 }
]
```

I have a method frameJsonArray that frames the above json and im making post request as follows,

```
 JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.requestUrl, frameJsonArray(),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    hideDialog();
                    error.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
    );
```

Im getting error in the above line of code where im making the request. How can I get this sorted?

Following is my error log

```
Error:(162, 46) error: constructor JsonArrayRequest in class JsonArrayRequest cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,Listener<JSONArray>,ErrorListener
found: int,String,JSONArray,<anonymous Listener<JSONObject>>,<anonymous ErrorListener>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Following is my frameJsonArrayMethod

```
public JSONArray frameJsonArray() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObject.put("login_type", "Android");
    jsonObject.put("username", email);
    jsonObject.put("password", password);
    jsonObject.put("short_name", null);
    jsonObject.put("ip","123.421.12.21");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put("Login");
jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

Log.d(TAG, "he;ll " + jsonArray.toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return jsonArray;
```

}

Comment: i have posted the error log

Comment: please correct your json data. complete double quota side of email. like "email"

Comment: yah i have done it

Comment: @JyotmanSingh Any ideas on How I can make a post request with those request parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();            
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                });
```

Source : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: yeah but How can I send my request parameter using the above code snippet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18052417/4854450, but for request to API, it's better to use Retrofit with GSON, it's faster than Volley and ASyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.requestUrl, frameJsonArray(),
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                hideDialog();
                error.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
);
```

Change JSONObject to JSONArray in onResponse()

**EDIT** The error coming because there is only one constructor in JsonArrayRequest i.e.

```
public JsonArrayRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener){}
```

source https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/e7cdf98078bc94a2e430d9edef7e9b01250765ac/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonArrayRequest.java

you are using some constructor with 5 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

once check your `JSON` , wrong format , you missed double quote.

```
[
 "Type",
 {
  "User": "email /** you missed double quote here **/,
  "password": "dimmer",

 }
]
```

Comment: i have corrected it, the error is upon making a json array request itself

Comment: the actual error is upon making jsonarrayrequest which is unresolved yet