# Try to POST JSONArray with volley

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, android-volley

I got an jsonarray like:

```
[{
    "color": -1,
    "fill": false,
    "id": 1,
    "radius": 154.613,
    "shapeText": "",
    "shapeType": "circle",
    "x1": 141.172,
    "x2": 0,
    "y1": 231.188,
    "y2": 0
}, {
    "color": -4569601,
    "fill": false,
    "id": 2,
    "radius": 0,
    "shapeText": "",
    "shapeType": "rectangle",
    "x1": 512.656,
    "x2": 606.781,
    "y1": 305.25,
    "y2": 413.502
}]
```

and I try to do POST to the server but I fail :[ 
I already get an jsonarray frm the server and I also did POST but for jsonobject to the server but I couldn't make it POST Jsonarray :[, anyone got any idea how to do it?

```
public class JSONPostArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONObject> {
JSONArray params;
public JSONPostArrayRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, JSONArray params) {
    super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    this.params=params;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody()  {
    if ( this.params != null && this.params.length() > 0) {
        return encodeParameters( this.params, getParamsEncoding());
    }
    return null;

}

private byte[] encodeParameters(JSONArray params, String paramsEncoding) {
    try {
        return params.toString().getBytes(paramsEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding, uee);
    }
}

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString =
                new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}
```

}

and my request done with this code:

```
public void updateDraw(ArrayList<Shape> shapes) {
    JSONArray jsonArrayShapes = new JSONArray();
    Log.d("START OF JSON ARRAY  ", shapes.toString());
    for (Shape shape : shapes) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjectShape = new JSONObject();
            jsonObjectShape.put("color", String.valueOf(shape.getColor()));
            jsonObjectShape.put("fill", String.valueOf(shape.isFill()));
            jsonObjectShape.put("radius", String.valueOf(shape.getRadius()));
            jsonObjectShape.put("shapeText", String.valueOf(shape.getShapeText()));
            jsonObjectShape.put("shapeType", String.valueOf(shape.getShapeType()));
            jsonObjectShape.put("x1", String.valueOf(shape.getX1()));
            jsonObjectShape.put("x2", String.valueOf(shape.getX2()));
            jsonObjectShape.put("y1", String.valueOf(shape.getY1()));
            jsonObjectShape.put("y2", String.valueOf(shape.getY2()));
            jsonObjectShape.put("id", String.valueOf(shape.getId()));
            jsonArrayShapes.put(jsonObjectShape);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("JSONARRAY = ", jsonArrayShapes.toString());
    }
    String shapeUrl = Main.GROUPS_URL + "/" + id + "/shape";
    Log.d("URL = ", shapeUrl);
    JSONPostArrayRequest jsonPostArrayRequest = new JSONPostArrayRequest(shapeUrl,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("onErrorResponse   ", error.toString());
                }
            }, jsonArrayShapes);
    requestQueue.add(jsonPostArrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: Please show your Volley code

Comment: just upload my code

Comment: the answer can only be in the logs of your server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volley - Sending a POST request using JSONArrayRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048806/volley-sending-a-post-request-using-jsonarrayrequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing your JSONArray into the request.

```
super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
```

That `null` parameter, as per the documentation

> A `JSONArray` to post with the request. Null is allowed and indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.

Therefore, I don't see why you need to extend `JsonRequest`, or especially why you typed it with `<JSONObject>`.

The `JsonArrayRequest` class already exists, you just need to give the `JSONArray` object as the third parameter there.