# Volley not sending the params while using JsonArrayRequest

Tags: android, arrays, android-volley

The Android code is not sending the parameters when using JsonArrayRequest.

If I use StringRequest instead of JsonArrayRequest how do I convert the response from String to JSONObject to display it in a RecyclerView?

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
final String userID = intent.getExtras().getString("userID");
recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.display_expenses_recycler_view_id);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, expensesDisplay_url, (String) null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                int count = 0;
                Log.i("Response", String.valueOf(response));
                while (count < response.length()) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                        ExpensesDetails expensesDetails = new ExpensesDetails(jsonObject.getString("Expenses"),
                                jsonObject.getString("Description"), jsonObject.getString("datetime"));
                        arrayList.add(expensesDetails);
                        count++;
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(DisplayExpenses.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("userID", userID);
        return params;
    }

};
Log.i("Array", String.valueOf(arrayList));
MySingleton.getMyInstance(DisplayExpenses.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
adapter = new RecyclerAdapterExpenses(arrayList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);View.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the result sent from the server:

```
[
  {
    "Expenses":"0",
    "Description":"car",
    "datetime":"2016-10-25 21:10:57"
  },
  {
    "Expenses":"2000",
    "Description":"Car",
    "datetime":"2016-10-25 21:46:05"
  },
  {
    "Expenses":"5000",
    "Description":"House payment",
    "datetime":"2016-10-25 21:47:11"
  },
  {
    "Expenses":"200",
    "Description":"",
    "datetime":"2016-10-26 20:51:42"
  },
  {
    "Expenses":"500",
    "Description":"",
    "datetime":"2016-10-26 23:55:21"
  }
]
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for what should be at `(String) null`. **That** is the data you are to POST

Comment: JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, expensesDisplay_url, userID,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {                                                          like this ??

Comment: I am not too sure that a String is that parameter. According to this post, it's a `JSONObject`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048806/volley-sending-a-post-request-using-jsonarrayrequest#18052417

Comment: if i choose to use StringRequest how will i convert the string response into JSONArray to display it in the recycler view ??

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do that, but I just updated my answer below

Comment: Worth mentioning: Retrofit+Gson may be better suited than Volley for your problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the user ID isn't being given? You have an empty RecyclerView until the Volley request finishes. And your `Log.i` statement happens before Volley completes, so you'll see an empty list...

You need an `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` within the `onResponse` call after the `while` loop to tell the adapter to display the data you added.

Not too sure what `View` is here... but you likely don't need the same adapter on two views.

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);View.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> if i tried to use StringRequest instead of JsonArrayRequest how will i convert the string response from String to JSONObject to display them in a RecyclerView

You have a `String response` from `onResponse`, so use the constructor for `JSONArray` that takes a `String`.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
```

Note: that requires a try-catch.