# JsonArrayRequest using Android Volley library (POST request)

Tags: android, android-volley

Iam using Volley library to post json array to `RestApi`. But i get an error **BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400**. I lookfor many articles [Volley - Sending a POST request using JSONArrayRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048806/volley-sending-a-post-request-using-jsonarrayrequest) but not get any solution yet. 
Here's my code,

```
final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    List<User> users = UserManager.composeUsers();
    jsonArray.put(users);

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.137.1:8080/create", jsonArray, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error: ", error.toString());
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return String.format("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        }

    };
    queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

In the above code `List<User> user` return a `java object`. I want to pass the `user` object to rest service.

Comment: If you go to the server with a browser, entering the url you are using, what do you get back? It should be a JSON String. If not, the server's the issue.

Comment: post hour logcat or error where r u facing problem

Comment: when i browse the URL I get the following response  `{
  "timestamp": 1488450781093,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
  "message": "Required request body content is missing: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter@ea984ded",
  "path": "/create"
}`

Comment: @Narendhran you are not passing the parameters that you required in your webapi.

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari what parameters should i pass ?? you mean the `user` object as json

Comment: **My log error**  *D/Error:: com.android.volley.ServerError*  *E/Volley: [323411] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://192.168.137.216:8080/create*

Comment: put your right content type and also define same in your web api

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari I am new to android brother, Iam not able to understand that you are all saying. If you have any good example or reff, send the link to me I 'll be very thankful to you. Thanks for your kind response.

Comment: @Narendhran follow this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/ as well website this is best for newbie