# How to retrieve the data from an url using volley which has no array name?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, mobile-application

The image contains the data which has no array name and I need to get the data which is in the image using volley.Help me with the code for it.
[image: -]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a **JSONArrayRequest** . When you parse the response, it's a ready to use JSONArray object. You can loop the array to get your JSONObject items by position.

This has been covered in this thread -> [Volley - Sending a POST request using JSONArrayRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048806/volley-sending-a-post-request-using-jsonarrayrequest)

Answer (score 0):

String url="https://earthquake.usgs.gov/archive/product/nearby-cities/ci39269503/ci/1593242325224/nearby-cities.json";
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();

```
            try {

               for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                   JSONObject citiesjsonObject=response.getJSONObject(i);
                   stringBuilder.append("Name : "+citiesjsonObject.getString("name")+
                           "\n"+"Distance : "+citiesjsonObject.getString("distance")+ "\n"
                           +"Population : "+citiesjsonObject.getString("population"));


                   stringBuilder.append("\n\n");
               }

                
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```